# unable to get Oauth2 token from auth server

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, resttemplate

I have an auth-server configured in spring with

```
clients
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("my-web-app")
        .secret("my-web-app-secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes(//
            "authorization_code",//
            "refresh_token",//
            "password"//
        ).scopes("openid")
```

Now I want to develop a command line application for the webapp. Hence I need to register one more client with a seperate client id and secret.
I have done something like this

```
.and()
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("my-cli")
        .secret("my-cli-secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","client_credentials")
        .scopes("read","write","trust").authorities("ROLE_USER");
```

What I want to achieve is use simply provide the username/password and the client app should be able to get the auth token from the auth server.

What I have tried and understood is I should be using Resource Owner password Grant. I have to use the spring Oauth2restTemplate after this. 
The problem in this configuration is when I m hitting the tokenuri i m getting

```
{
error: "unauthorized"
error_description: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

and everytime it is hitting with the anonymous user.

Comment: Add the stacktrace after enabling debug level for package : `org.springframework.*`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to user username/password for obtaining the access token you definitely need to use `grant_type=password`.

You also don't need to specify `.inMemory()` twice - just two clients with `.and()` between them.

So the configuration then have to be something like

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
                    // First client 
            .withClient("my-web-app")
            .secret("my-web-app-secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes(//
                    "authorization_code",//
                    "refresh_token",//
                    "password"//
            ).scopes("openid")
            // Second Client(CLI)
            .and()
            .withClient("my-cli")
            .secret("my-cli-secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER");
}
```

**And other very important thing** - you need to set the `Authorization:` header in the http request for the token. So the header should be

```
"Authorization: Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes())
```

This header is checked before the username\password and defines that the client(CLI in your case) is an authorized client (this can cause the error from your question).

That would be really good if you can add the code how exactly you use `Oauth2RestTemplate`

Comment: I have added the above code as you mentioned and trying to access it using the resttemplate
    `MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    requestParams.add("grant_type", "password");
    requestParams.add("client_id", "commandline");
    requestParams.add("username", "user");
    requestParams.add("password", "pwd");
    headers = HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("ContentType", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.add("Authorization: Basic ", Base64.encodeBase64String(("my-cli" + ":" + "my-cli-secret").getBytes()));`

Comment: But I m getting this message as the response `AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Aug 11 10:22:42 IST 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={message=Bad credentials, type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException}]`

Comment: Try `headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String(("my-cli" + ":" + "my-cli-secret").getBytes()));` (`Basic ` here is part of value, not header name)

Comment: Still getting the exception `{message=Bad credentials, type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException}`

Comment: Are the users registered using the first client will be available to use the second client?

Comment: I think it should be, but you can try debugging that part